# Is there a way to check if the AWS SDK is authenticated by IAM?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam, identity

Some of the EC2 servers that we use have an IAM role associated with them and some don't. Currently, we manually provide the credentials to each AWS service that we use via custom environment variables. Is there a way to check if any AWS service is already authenticated? Can `config.credentials` be used in this case and does it store the credentials when authenticated via IAM?

Comment: Why are you talking about "AWS service(s)" but also only about EC2? Are you only referring to EC2? Is the question simply how you can find out whether instance has an instance profile associated?

Comment: @luk2302 yes I need to find out whether an instance has an IAM role associated or not, as it is the recommended way of setting credentials.

Comment: From within an instance itself or from the outside? Do you want the instance itself to check if it has credentials or do you want to basically go through a list of all instances and see which ones have credentials and which ones don't

Comment: @luk2302 within the instance itself

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/instancedata-data-retrieval.html

Comment: If you run `aws sts get-caller-identity`, it will return an ARN that looks like `arn:aws:sts::ACCOUNT_ID:assumed-role/` if the instance has a role, `arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNT_ID:user/` if running with long-lived credentials. This, of course, won't mean anything if the user credentials are configured within your program.